# Export events to Multiple Google Calendars from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I need the script to export events from my spreadsheet to their respective calendars (column J), without duplicates. I have the below script, but haven't been able to get it to export events to my various calendars.

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();// Set multiple script properties in one call.
scriptProperties.setProperties({
    'CF Library': 'cflibrary@efriends44221.org',
    'Arts/Crafts': 'efriends44221.org_a63hoveiu9jqisb826bllsjkp8@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Computers & Technology': 'efriends44221.org_mvov2vcook8amqltimt67i5lb0@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Library Closed': 'efriends44221.org_e4lvfr74rchoanhaqkmh8evo4c@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Story Time': 'efriends44221.org_6hc52m954fumu33o8tiob03mhs@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Board Meeting': 'efriends44221.org_g9dkgvpoenbpakshoaj7i84bj8@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Continuing Education': 'efriends44221.org_aur9f7fgj401biph9370l7vdp8@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Movies': 'efriends44221.org_c7v1c9hs041ogprqasaguc6cq4@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Summer Reading Program': 'efriends44221.org_r7nfru4r624a41ifqu2n540qss@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Book Sale': 'efriends44221.org_fr19jra74rs5ia4i4ortd44sgg@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Exhibit': 'efriends44221.org_151qtt5afnr7hs6fae4g05vrjg@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Music': 'efriends44221.org_uo2j384ldonbasja8drpl8520k@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Tax Preparation': 'efriends44221.org_lhdtbjunpjqtn52k9o5gkgol5k@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Business & Career': 'efriends44221.org_gboa7mo6i9uvothv4s1q929ne8@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Health & Wellness': 'efriends44221.org_gh97a27i0bqc93hndpr08435uc@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Non-Profit & Community': 'efriends44221.org_mfm9u656llmtubnvvm8h2ehjak@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Workshop/Class': 'efriends44221.org_gbarc152o2h55c67fc8cpshqfo@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Club/Discussion Group': 'efriends44221.org_c2a7vkhh3hlvlh9ijkdlcqin1s@group.calendar.google.com',
    'History': 'efriends44221.org_rnto9utgss0h2ltb83hp203634@group.calendar.google.com',
    'Special Event': 'efriends44221.org_7u2tqcktujiautq2qes591p8tk@group.calendar.google.com'});

function ExportEvents() {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Events");
  var headerRows = 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var calendarName = sheet.getRange('J:J').getValue();
  var calendarId = ScriptProperties.getProperty(calendarName);
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var timeZone = cal.getTimeZone();
  ss.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(timeZone);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue;
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);
    var title = row[1];           
    var tstart = setTimeToDate(date,row[2]);
    var tstop = setTimeToDate(date,row[3]);
    Logger.log('date = '+date+'tstart = '+tstart+'  tstop = '+tstop);
    var location = row[4];
    var description = row[5];
    var type = row[6];
    var times = row[7];
    var enddate = row[8];
    var calname = row[9];
    var id = row[10];
    var status = row[11];
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
      event.setTitle('---');
    }catch(e){
      if (calname = 'CF Library') {
        var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop,      {description:description,location:location});// create a "normal" event
      }else if (calname = 'Arts/Crafts') {
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop,{description:description,location:location});
      }else if (calname = 'Computers & Technology') {
        var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:description,location:location});
      }else if (calname = 'Library Closed') {
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:description,location:location});
      }else if (calname = 'Story Time') {
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:description,location:location});
      }
  row[10] = newEvent.getId();  // Update the data array with event ID
  Logger.log('Event Created');// while debugging
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(row[10]);// make it an event Series
}
event.setTitle(title);
event.setDescription(desc);
event.setLocation(loc);
if(type=='PM'){ // Per Month
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addMonthlyRule().times(times)
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);// we need to keep start and stop otherwise it becomes an AllDayEvent if only start is used
}else if(type=='PW'){ // Per Week
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().times(times)
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}else if(type=='PD'){ //Per Day
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(times)
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}else if(type=='PY'){ //Per Year
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().times(times)
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}else if(type=='MCD'){//MCD is Monthly on a certain day.
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addMonthlyRule().onlyOnMonthDay(times);// Creates a rule that recurs every month on a certain day of the month.
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}else if(type=='TTH'){//TTH is 2 days per week - Tues, Thurs.
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY]).until(new Date(enddate));
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}else if(type=='MWF'){//MWF is 3 days per week - Mon, Weds, Fri.
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY]).until(new Date(enddate));
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}
  data[i] = row ;
  }
dataRange.setValues(data);

 for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue;
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 1;// Is the start row & also the header row.
      var dataR = sheet.getDataRange();
      var data = dataR.getValues();
      var rowNum = startRow;
      var destRow = Number(startRow)+Number(i);
        Logger.log(startRow+' '+i+' '+(startRow+i))
        Logger.log(startRow+' '+i+' '+(Number(startRow)+Number(i)))
       sheet.getRange(Number(++destRow)-1, 12).setValue("Event Exported");
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error?  If there is an error, what line is it on?  If there is no error, have you used the debugger, stepped through the code and checked EVERY line and variable for what you expect and what is being returned?  [Breakpoints and Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: Yes it starts with a Typeerror on line 8 (getCalendarById(calendarId). If I alter that in some way it then gives another error line 9 for TimeZone, if that is changed it then gives an error for the line 32 (var newEvent = cal.createEvent...).

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code.  Do you have `ScriptProperties` set more than once?  I'm wondering if there is a conflict somewhere else in your code.  Do you have an AddOn?  A Library?  Anything could conflict with this code?  Search the function name for another function name with the same name.  I don't know.  There is something strange going on.

Comment: The only place it comes up is where i defined the var scriptProperties, right below where i set the properties, and then where i referenced it in the function ExportEvents().

Comment: Try removing the curly braces `{}`.  You don't need those.

Comment: @Administrator Issue seems that you are using `ScriptProperties` with capital `S` in `ExportEvents()`, but you have defined `scriptProperties` with small `s`. GAS is case sensitive.

Comment: @ Sandy Good remove them from where specifically?

Comment: @user1989 I changed it so they match. Getting this TypeError: Cannot call method "getTimeZone" of null.

Comment: I got it to work if I put a specific cell like "J10" in getRange() for var calendarName = dataSheet.getRange().getValue();. When I use "J:J" I get TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of null.

Comment: The script only works when this line var calendarName = dataSheet.getRange().getValue(); has a specific cell referenced like "J3." I need to access the entire column. Most often will be exporting multiple events to multiple calendars.

Comment: In addition, if I enter "J2:J" into the getRange() it exports the event to default calendar (The one defaulted to the google account) and not to the calendar selected in column J it's aligned with.

Comment: @SandyGood thank you for all your help. I figured it out!

Comment: @user1989 thank you for all your help. I figured it out!

Comment: What was wrong? Can you post an answer for what the solution is?

Answer (score 0):

```
var destRow = Number(headerRows)+Number(i);
    Logger.log(headerRows+' '+i+' '+(headerRows+i))
    Logger.log(headerRows+' '+i+' '+(Number(headerRows)+Number(i)))
var calendarName = sheet.getRange(Number(destRow), 10).getValue();
```

I added the var destRow, with the Loggers, and in the var calendarName for the getRange() I added (Number(destRow), 10).